# how to pass checkbox value to text input using Ajax and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to evaluate the values of all checked checkboxes and pass the result
to html text input I'm trying to do that using php and ajax but I have no good result please help
 this is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
          {

            $("#check").click(function ()
            {
                var data = $("#check").val();
                //get selected parent option 

                $.ajax(
                        {
                            type: "GET",
                            data:data,
                            url: "total.php?val="+data,

                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data)
                            {

                                $("#tot").html(data);
                            }
                        });
            });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "voucher_test");

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM vouchers where cat_id = 1");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $userSet[] = $row;
    }

    ?>  

<form   action="index.php" method="post">
    <?php
            foreach ($userSet as $key=>$value){
                echo $value['service_name']."<input type='checkbox' id='check'  name='{$value['service_name']}' value='{$value['service_price']}'>";

            }
    ?>
    <br>
    <div id="tot"></div>
</form>
```

and this is `total.php`

```
    <?php
      $itot = 5;
      $itot+=$_GET['val'];
      echo"<input type='text' value='$itot'>";
```

Comment: What is the expected/desired behavior? What is actually happening?  Don't just dump a bunch of code and say "it doesn't work".  That doesn't help us help you.  Personally, I don't see the benefit of the PHP code at all.  From what you have, it looks like it could all be done client-side.

Comment: Remove your ajax call and do this with JS-only. No reason to use ajax and PHP for this. It just adds complexity and an extra http round trip to the server and back.

Comment: Also, you should not give all of your checkboxes the same ID.  Your event binding will only attach to the first element with that ID.  You should probably do the event binding based on class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to sent value to server `y` o `n`

```
var data = ($("#check").is(":checked") ? 'y' : 'n';
```

If you want send the value of checkbox, try this code:

```
var data = new FormData();//Create FormData

if($("#check").is(":checked")){//Verified if the input os checked
    data.append('data-check',$("#check").val());//Add data of the checkbox to FormData
}

$.ajax(
     {
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        url: "total.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data)
                {
                    $("#tot").html(data);
                }
});
```

In yur php

```
$_GET['data-check'];
```

Comment: You have a type in your code ( missing `"` in line `url: "total.php" ` )

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to use the total.php file, but if you really want to use it I recommend to change your code to this:

```
<?php
  $itot = 5;
  $itot+=$_GET['val'];
  echo"<input type='text' value='" . $itot . "'>";
```

The only change is the concatenation of the string you are printing